# how to set default company logo in odoo 12?

Tags: python, odoo

I 'am trying to set a default logo for the company, but nothing changes 
I tried this code

```
class logocompany(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.company'

@api.model
def _default_company_image(self):
    image_path = modules.get_module_resource('auto_product', 'static/src/img', 'autoparts.png')
    return tools.image_resize_image_big(base64.b64encode(open(image_path, 'rb').read()))

logo = fields.Binary(default=_default_company_image  )
```

any help well be apprcited